# Occurrences of voiced VS unvoiced 'th'

Tags: phonemes

Is there a resource for determining how common one or the other is in English? I doubt that it varies between BrE vs AmE etc

Comment: Could you provide information about any research you have already done

Comment: Have you tried googling "frequency of english phonemes" or similar? (First you should consider what exactly you want to know.)

Comment: Why the "diphthongs" tag?

Comment: No, it doesn't but it does vary between BrE/AmE and Irish English. The Irish use t for the unvoiced th.

Comment: The etymology is usually a giveaway. /ð/ appears overwhelmingly in articles, demonstratives, conjunctions, quantifiers, and other function words, where it's Germanic in origin (a product of Grimm's Law, in fact). /θ/, on the other hand, appears overwhelmingly in lexical items, often borrowed from Greek.

Comment: My untutored ear tells me that where 'th' occurs in a word makes a difference.  in the middle of words of two or more syllables the hard 'th' seems to predominate (i.e. I can only come up with 'Arthur' as a soft 'th' word).  Where 'th' is at the end of a word it seems to be usually soft, as in 'bath', 'sloth' except with a final 'e' (as in lathe').  But I am not being scientific.  It's a suggesting possible starting point.

Comment: @user888379 - sheer incompetence?

Comment: @StuartF - the specific question was looking for a way to find that out, so, it's a bit circular to ask if I searched for the thing I was asking about how to look for :-)

Comment: @Tuffy: you're not actually saying much different from John Lawler, but it may not be obvious. You're right that non-initial 'th' is often voiced  /ð/, but these cases are mearly always inherited Germanic words, and often the result of a grammatical change, (such as _bath_ -> _bathe_, or _breath_ -> _breathe_, or _mouth_ -> _mouth_). In Greek derived words it is usually unvoiced /θ/ even between vowel: _mathematical_, _pathetic_, _hypothermic_. _Rhythm_ (and _rhythmic_) is an exception, and _Gothic_ is an exception the other way (not Greek).

Comment: @ Colin Fine.  Yes, that is fair.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is here. I'm not sure why you couldn't find it...

https://github.com/prendradjaja/phoneme-frequencies/blob/master/local_target/q1_frequencies

ð = 2.99%

θ = 0.40%

Comment: Indeed, it seems so obvious now...